# Java netbean Calling database error (com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException)

Tags: java, mysql

> ```
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'character' at line 1
> ```

I'm pretty dumbfounded with this error. Basicly had this base code for every of my project with database but somehow it's just dead.

```
public ArrayList<Character> display()
    {
        ArrayList<Character> collection = new ArrayList<>();
        try
        {
            stat = (Statement) connect.createStatement();

            result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM character");

            while(result.next())
            {
                Character a = new Character(
                            result.getString("user"),
                            result.getInt("win"),
                            result.getInt("lose"),
                            result.getInt("draw")
                            );
                collection.add(a);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return collection;
    }
```

```
        chara = new Character();

        for(int i = 0; i< chara.display().size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println("asd");
            String message = chara.display().get(i).getUser();
            System.out.println(message);
        }
```

Comment: For more info the bug got triggered by chara.display().size() in which it redirected tot the long post. And yes i have triple checked all of the spelling for the database

Comment: The problem is 'character' is a reserved word, either double quote it or change it.

Answer (score 1):

In MariaDB, [`CHARACTER` is a reserved keyword](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/reserved-words/) Therefore you cannot use it as such in your query. You need to put it between backthick ( ` )

```
/* ... */
stat = (Statement) connect.createStatement();

result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `character`;");

while(result.next())
{
     Character a = new Character(
                            result.getString("user"),
                            result.getInt("win"),
                            result.getInt("lose"),
                            result.getInt("draw")
                            );
     collection.add(a);
}
/* ... */
```

Comment: Yeah it worked! Never realized that character is a keyword thanks for your help there!